# software for convolutional neural net for binary image classification

Tags: windows, python, gui, machine-learning

Are there standalone software solutions which use convolutional neural nets for binary image classification? Could be open-source but should be easy to use if that's possible.

- should run on Windows 10
- does not have to be open source necessarily
- GUI would be preferable but if it is an python library there should be not too many adjustments

It could be rather rudimentary but it should use convolutional neural nets for classification.

Comment: As your question currently stands, it's hard to understand exactly what you're asking. Could you please give more information like compatible OS, does it have to be open source, and from what standpoint do you mean easy to use? Are you a developer or an end user and want a GUI?

Comment: Hi. Sure. It should run on Windows 10. It does not have to be open source necessarily. GUI would be preferable but if it is an python library there should be not too many adjustments. It could be rather rudimentary but it should use convolutional neural nets for classification.

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example of the sort of thing that you are looking for is [NVIDIA Digits 3](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS), *Deep Learning GPU Training System*, which uses [opencv](http://opencv.org/) and [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) but gives it a web interface for training deep learning models.

It will, *potentially*, run on Windows 10 with some effort **but** to get a sensible speed requires the use of one, *or more*, NVIDIA graphics cards for GPU processing.

If you don't have an NVISIA GPU, *or do but don't wish to have your machine tied up for hours,* then [this article](https://www.learnopencv.com/nvidia-digits-3-on-ec2/) covers installing and running it on an Amazon AWS EC2 g2.2xlarge, *or g2.8xlarge if you are ready to spend more,* instance. *There is a [linked article](http://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-example-using-nvidia-digits-3-on-ec2/) here that covers using a pre-installed instance.*  This saves all of the steps of getting DIGITS installed and running on your windows machine.

- Get started with no code to write
- Alows examination and customisation of the learning models
- Monitor progress with a smart phone
- Caffe and beta support for Torch
- Code is all Free, Gratis & Open Source
- AWS EC2 g2.2xlarge currently costs $0.60 per hour to run
- Web GUI, as shown in [this](https://youtu.be/QZaAcl_F9R0) video, shows a number of options and then, when training a, progress with the accuracy achieved so far during training and a final accuracy achived.

Comment: Hi. Thx for the input. I'll try that.

Comment: The pre-installed AWS is probably the easiest option.

Comment: Well worth reading http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/06/06/hands-on-with-the-nvidia-digits-devbox-for-deep-learning/

Comment: Very interesting thx.